# Why is my Custom Error Handler overwritten by some other handler?

Tags: angular, error-handling

I have created a custom error handler and registered in the `main.ts` file via an ApplicationConfig.

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [
        ...
        importProvidersFrom(BrowserAnimationsModule),
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler },
        ...
    ]
};
```

If I am not putting my handler after the importProvidersFrom it is overwritten by another error handler.

Why is this overwritten and by what?

**Angular Dev Tools**

In the Screenshot there are three handler registered on the root element. The last one is my custom error handler. Where are the other two coming from?

[image: Injector Tree from root]

**nx report**

```
 NX   Report complete - copy this into the issue template

   Node   : 18.13.0
   OS     : win32-x64
   npm    : 9.6.6

   nx (global)        : 17.1.1
   nx                 : 17.1.3
   @nx/js             : 17.1.3
   @nx/jest           : 17.1.3
   @nx/linter         : 17.1.3
   @nx/eslint         : 17.1.3
   @nx/workspace      : 17.1.3
   @nx/angular        : 17.1.3
   @nx/cypress        : 17.1.3
   @nx/devkit         : 17.1.3
   @nx/eslint-plugin  : 17.1.3
   @nrwl/tao          : 17.1.3
   @nx/web            : 17.1.3
   @nx/webpack        : 17.1.3
   typescript         : 5.2.2
   ---------------------------------------
   Community plugins:
   @progress/kendo-angular-buttons      : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs   : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-dialog       : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns    : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-excel-export : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-grid         : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-icons        : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-indicators   : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-inputs       : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-l10n         : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-label        : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-layout       : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-listview     : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-navigation   : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-notification : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-scheduler    : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-tooltip      : 14.1.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`importProvidersFrom(BrowserAnimationsModule)` is pulling the `BrowserModule`.

`BrowserModule` provides a default handler.

If you want to use animations, you should be using `provideAnimations()` instead.